# Iterate through different tabs of excel, extract data and put into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I have a single excel workbook, df, that contains two tabs, **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**. I would like to extract values from both tabs and create a new dataframe using openpyxl/Pandas.

**Sheet1**

```
      2021    2021
      q1      q2
ID    1       1
ID2   3       3
name  A       A
```

**Sheet2**

```
  2021    2021
      q1      q2
ID    2       2
ID2   2       2
name  B       B
```

[image]

**Desired**

```
quarter year ID   ID2   name

q1     2021  1    3     A
q1     2021  2    2     B
```

**Doing**

```
#Load openpyxl

import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("df.xlsx")
ws1 = wb.worksheets[0]
ws2 = wb.worksheets[1]


#create loop that will iterate over the first row and end at 2nd column for each sheet

for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row = 0, max_col = 1, max_row = 3, min_col = 0 
                            for cell in row:
                                 print(cell.value, end="")
                            print()


for row in ws2.iter_rows(min_row = 0, max_col = 1,  max_row = 3, min_col = 0 
                            for cell in row:
                                 print(cell.value, end="")
                            print()
```

I am having trouble with creating a new dataframe from the values collected. Any suggestion or input is appreciated. I am still troubleshooting this.

Comment: Why not just use [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Comment: ok sure, I was thinking it would be easier to use openpyxl to grab data from cells and then create a new dataframe. Thanks. I will look this up.

Answer (score 1):

pd.read_excel can read a specific sheet or multiple, like shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
dict_dfs = pd.read_excel("df.xlsx", sheet_name=[0,1])

df = pd.concat(dict_dfs)
```

Afterwards you can iterate over the dictionary of dataframes or combine them directly if the format of the excel files already allows it.

Example, after loading with sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'2021': {'_': 'q1', 'ID': '2', 'ID2': '2', 'name': 'B'},
 '2021.1': {'_': 'q2', 'ID': '2', 'ID2': '2', 'name': 'B'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'2021': {'_': 'q1', 'ID': '1', 'ID2': '3', 'name': 'A'},
 '2021.1': {'_': 'q2', 'ID': '1', 'ID2': '3', 'name': 'A'}})


df = pd.concat([df1.T,df2.T])
df.index = df.index.str.split(".").str[0]
print(df)
#        _ ID ID2 name
# 2021  q1  2   2    B
# 2021  q2  2   2    B
# 2021  q1  1   3    A
# 2021  q2  1   3    A
```

The `.T`gives you the transposed dataframe.

Comment: ok thank you. Does this say that: df essentially will hold any values that are extracted from sheets 0 and 1?

Comment: @Lynn it should do that as long as the data is stored in a typical table format. Rows x columns. If you get an error you also can load the workbooks with openpyxl like you did, and then load the data into pandas like so: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(ws1.values)'

Comment: ok I will do this, one more question please, - when I run the loop, it is merely printing. How would I capture it/store it in the dataframe?  Would I create a variable in front of the loop?

Comment: @Lynn I would not loop at all. Pandas is very powerful and can do most likely what you want to achive without any loops, i try to create an example, 1 moment.

Comment: ah ok thank you for posting, I will try this.  I think this is combining or concatenating two different dataframes. I am trying to iterate through specified cells along many different sheets, extract the data and essentially create a new dataframe. I will try this though and see if I get desired outcome. Thank you for the insight!